# Getting org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException while handling a dropdown

Tags: java, selenium

I have modified the code and still getting the same error:

```
    String[] expectedOptions = {"Name (A to Z)", "Name (Z to A)", "Price (low to high)", "Price (high to low)"};
    List<String> eOptions = Arrays.asList(expectedOptions);
    hp.sort().click();
    Select select = new Select(hp.sort());
    List<WebElement> values = select.getOptions();
    List<String> value = new ArrayList<>();
    for (WebElement option : values) {
        value.add(option.getText());
    }
    for (int i = 1; i < eOptions.size(); i++) {
        if (eOptions.contains(value.get(i))) {
            select.selectByVisibleText(values.get(i).getText());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`hp` is `WebElement` I guess. Why the `hp.sort()`? Why calling multiple times `s.get(i).getText()`?
For selecting by visible text you have to click the dropdown first to make the option's text visible.

This is how I would do it:

```
    List<String> expectedOptions = Arrays.asList("Name (Z to A)", "Price (low to high)", "Price (high to low)");
    WebElement dropdown = driver.findElement(By.id("dropdown")); // dummy locator
    dropdown.click();
    Select select = new Select(dropdown);
    List<WebElement> options = select.getOptions();
    List<String> optionsTexts = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (WebElement option: options) {
        optionsTexts.add(option.getText());
    }
    if (expectedOptions.size() == options.size()) {
        for (int i = 0; i < expectedOptions.size(); i++) {
            if (expectedOptions.get(i).equals(options.get(i).getText())) {
                System.out.println("Option at index " + i + ": match - OK");
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("Option at index " + i + ": does not match - ERR");
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Different options size from expected." + System.lineSeparator() + "Expected: " + expectedOptions + System.lineSeparator() + "Detected on page: " + optionsTexts);
    }
```